# Airport card not working

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth, airport

I have a Macbook pro mid 2010. A time ago I replaced my superdrive with an extra hard drive. All works fine. But I replaced the second hard drive, and managed to damage the Airport connector (a tiny piece of plastic got stuck when I tried to reconnect it).

I've searched google for my options. I found out that the airport card is for wifi and bluetooth. Bluetooth works fine to my surprise. But the ethernet cable drives me insane!

I tried an external wifi adapter, it doesn't work in yosemite (but it works in bootcamp). Sure I've seen all the hacks and programs to get it to work in Mac. But this doesn't work in Yosemite.

**So I want to know my options:**

- Is the motherboard damaged (the connector on the motherboard,
  bluetooth still works though)? Replacement not an option in this
  case?
- Is the cable damaged and can I simply order a new cable, attach it to the existing airport card and insert it?
- Do I need to order a whole new airport card with connector cable?
- Do I need to give up hope and try to live with my ethernet cable?

Thanks guys!

MacBook Pro (13-inch Mid 2010), OS X Yosemite (10.10.1)

Comment: Are you able to see what you damaged in terms of the Airport Card? Was it  the physical board or the ribbon cable? Normally, you can purchase a replacement Airport Card/Ribbon Cable and replace it (its a tedious task but not too difficult. Involves removing the Display as the card/cable sits under the hinge area)

Comment: Did you seriously ask faraway strangers on the internet if your cables/connectors are damaged, without posting clear, high-resolution photos of the cables/connectors in question?

Comment: The connector on the motherboard and the cable had a few pins that got misaligned , but I managed to align them properly again. You can't see damage at this point. That is why I don't know what the problem is. The airport card itself is fine, it is just the connector on the cable or motherboard that doesn't work properly. But Bluetooth still works, so a part of the connector still works, since it is the same cable and Bluetooth is embedded in the airport card. I know how to replace the cable (YouTube, ifixit,..) but I want to know what is likely to be the problem before I order a new cable.